# emulated external storage (sdcard0) and mounted external storage (sdcard1)

Tags: android, storage

As far as I know, there are three types of storage among Android devices. Internal storage, emulated external storage and mounted external storage, like SD-Card.
SO what the differences between them.
My problems is that I want to scan images from external storage, so how to support these different kinds of devices.

If a devices has both emulated external storage (sdcard0) and mounted external storage (sdcard1) how to scan both of them.
Until now my code snippet looks like below,

```
        "/DCIM",
        "/DCIM/Camera",
        "/DCIM/100MEDIA",
        // Many Samsung phones mount the external sd card to /sdcard/external_sd
        "/external_sd/DCIM",
        "/external_sd/DCIM/Camera",
        "/external_sd/DCIM/100MEDIA"
```

anyone can help maintain the list. Or maybe the better way is to use some SDK build in methods instead of hard coded.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: All the paths/dirs you mention are non existent. So what do you mean with them? You should start with getExternalStorageDirectory or getExternalFleDir(s). And most certainly you will never obtain the path to a removable SD card. You have to ask the user to indicate it.

Comment: I assembled the dirs listed above with the getExternalStorageDirectory method, but still could not scan the photos from sdcard1.

Comment: For the first three that is possible. But for the last three not. So i wonder what you do with the last three. Why not show complete code? What do you mean with sdcard1 ? As said before Android will not tell you the path to a micro SD card.

Comment: the project hosted on github, you can find the complete code [here ](https://github.com/haiwen/seadroid/blob/master/src/com/seafile/seadroid2/gallery/ImageManager.java)

Comment: now the code only supports scanning photos on emulated storage (whose root dir value is sdcard0), I need to add support for mounted external sdcard (whose root dir value is sdcard1). Do you have any idea on how to implement this. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I already told you that:  let the user indicate the path. You don't have to add support or what ever you call it because it will be just a path to a different directory.

Comment: so could you show me some examples or reference or tutorials, I have no idea about this, thanks.

Comment: So you did not understand what i said and proposed. Please hire a translator.

Comment: I totally understand what you said, I just want to find some reference relate to letting user choose path. Because I have to consider a lot of circumstances like, SD card, USB removable and so on

Comment: Then what is the problem? You need a file/directory picker to let the user choose a directory. You can use an external one or make your own. There is nothing more in it. You can even do without if you just let the user type in the path.

Comment: if you use the app I am working on now, you wont say that, because it asks user to choose a remote folder to upload. And now it also asks user to choose a local dir, too complicated I think. the app is here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.seafile.seadroid2

Comment: I had a look and installed it. But as i have to make an account first and did not do that i cannot do anything with the app. It asks permissions for some media files but then i know still nothing. I would like to see which files are going to be synchronised. Which directories. You will give the user an option to indicate which folders to synchronise? According your comments here it seems not. The info in the playstore is not telling what gets synchronised and how the user can determine that.

Comment: yeah, I didnt provide user options to choose sync dirs, only scans DCIM dirs for photo syncing (the algorithm suppose only one external storage exists out there, which obviously incorrect). BTW, you can go here https://cloud.seafile.com/accounts/register/ to sign up an account to use the app.

Comment: Thanks for the invitation. I will not register at the moment though as that would help little to solve your problem. I think you app will be more valuable if the user can indicate the directories to be synchronized. Once he can he can indicate external or removable too.

Comment: I have been working on that, and thanks for your patience.